# Are there common threat signatures to look for in logs?

Tags: windows, linux, logging

I'm using ELK to grab, store and analyze logs.
I would like to automate a bit the search process with tools like Etsy's 411.

I'm aware of the yara rules and so forth, but it's a bit too malware-focused. Is there a set of rules publicly available of searches/signatures to look for in Windows/Linux logs?

For instance I'd like to search for multiple root connexions in a certain amount of time, for failed passwords and so forth. Is there a kind of shared things "not to forgot"?

Comment: https://github.com/Cyb3rWard0g/ThreatHunter-Playbook

Comment: Correct: Each device has its own set of signatures - there are SIEM Extensions, which categorise events, allowing to you to search on a general level.  E.g SIEM aggregators which classifying AV Logs all as 'Malware Events' etc. 

My suggestion would be to use GitHub and search for specifc Use Cases (e.g 25 Failed SSH Logins).


For Windows logs, then I suggest that you use Windows Event Logging. There is a whole wealth of information online relating to Windows event categorization.